# How to Enable Flash Plugin in Webview?

Tags: android, flash, webview

How to Enable Flash Plugin in Webview Browser?

Answer (score 16):

You just need to enable the plugins for the webview, like this :

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

I think you also need Flash to be installed, like in Android 2.2 and above.
Hope this helps.

*This method is now deprecated, I'll try to explain this more in detail. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginsEnabled%28boolean%29)*

Comment: You also may need `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the manifest if its apk > 3.0

Comment: Don't know for the "hardwareAccelerated", but the method I proposed is now deprecated. [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginsEnabled%28boolean%29) I'll try to explain this more in detail.

Answer (score 11):

I believe that you can

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

will work.

Comment: This is the correct answer, now that setPluginsEnabled() is deprecated.
But the second line in your code is meaningless. All you do is setting a constant to another constant, which you get by accessing the runtime object. I suggest you remove the second line and change the third line to:
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

Comment: Okay. I edited my sample. Thanks for the advice, sorry I'm mad late.

Answer (score 1):

setPluginsEnabled() and setPluginsEnabled() are deprecated.

To make Flash Player work in a WebView you need to enable hardware acceleration in your AdroidManifest.xml.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

You can also individually enable it for your WebView by using

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Comment: Did you mean setPluginsEnabled and setPluginState?

Comment: Any Fruitful solutions in 2020?

these are deprecated and not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

is deprecated now, instead use this:

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this lines of code

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

instead of using

```
 webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Its work fine...

Comment: webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON); is deprecated in api 18 and above

Comment: Its deprecated now aswell

Answer (score -3):

```
  package com.ageofwar2;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
         /** com.ageofwar2 */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


        String url ="file:///android_asset/Flash.swf"; //AgeOfWar2.swf
        WebView mWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON); 
        webview.loadUrl();
```

Comment: You should write some kind of explanation, how did you enable the flash for example

Comment: It should be `webview.loadUrl(url);`