# What happens (under the cover) when I click the Play "button" in YouTube?

Tags: android, webview, html5-video, android-webview, webchromeclient

1. Note 1: This question refers to
   **HTML5** videos only, not Flash videos.
2. Note 2: Also, it specifically
   targets HTML5 video playing on
   **Android**.

Given the following HTML5 video in YouTube:

```
<div id="player">
<video poster="data:image/gif;
base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" 
src="http://v19.lscache2.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?begin=0&amp;itag=18&amp;
ipbits=0ampsignature=151700E49EA1B695940D89926C1C07CDF0C176F0.B7DE0453C70BFBA0BA644DE7F6BBB72E9EE43B5F&amp;
sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Coc%3AU0hPSVRSUl9FSkNOOV9MTFZF&amp;
sver=3&amp;
ratebypass=yes&amp;expire=1304474400&amp;len=265000&amp;key=yt1&amp;ip=0.0.0.0&amp;
id=55884c15b4baba8f&amp;el=home&amp;yms=5602568839599417322&amp;app=youtube_mobile" class="bn" width="1" height="2" id="player_VYhMFbS6uo8">
</video>
</div>
```

I can identify the `src=` attribute as a URL being loaded into... what exactly?

I know that [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) can't play HTML5 videos by itself, so it hands them over to [WebChromeClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html): When I **touch** that familiar [right-pointing arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791035/what-does-install-flash-plugin-in-webview-mean) in the middle of the image representing the clip, Android switches automatically to a different activity that plays the video, instead of playing it inside WebView.

Now, I would like to start playing the video in exactly the same manner but from within my app, **without** the user having to "click" that [right-pointing arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791035/what-does-install-flash-plugin-in-webview-mean).

I tried to simply hand over that `src=` URL (http://v19.lscache2.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?begin...) to WebView, thinking that this would trigger `WebChromeClient.onShowCustomView()` just as what happens when I click the [right-pointing arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791035/what-does-install-flash-plugin-in-webview-mean), but... nothing really happens when I do that.

So, I am wondering: What actually happens, from `WebView` and `WebChromeClient` point of view, when I click that [right-pointing arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791035/what-does-install-flash-plugin-in-webview-mean)?

What do I need to do in order to "click" that [right-pointing arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791035/what-does-install-flash-plugin-in-webview-mean)?

Update: Thanks to the comment from @dronus I found the following in LogCat (after clicking the play button **manually**):

```
05-03 19:35:07.296: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(121):
setDataSource('http://v19.lscache2.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?begin=0
&itag=18
&ipbits=0
&signature=BB85C25344502EF07EC970250EFBF6661098373E.6A7E108FA6F48A0741CDF7A356B0E1474F185195
&sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Coc%3AU0hPSVRTVl9FSkNOOV9MTVpJ
&sver=3
&ratebypass=yes
&expire=1304488800
&len=265000
&key=yt1
&ip=0.0.0.0
&id=55884c15b4baba8f
&el=watch
&yms=5602637908081220405
&app=youtube_mobile')
```

The question remains: What triggers this?

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger to figure out what `Activity` is actually launched to play the video?

Comment: @dronus LogCat shows that the activity is `MediaPlayer` with lots of Log.i()'s from `QC_CORE` and some Log.d()'s from `QCvdec`. I don't know, however, what starts the activity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guesss that an Intent is launched to display the video with the specfied url and all other attributes.

Have you tried to launch an Intent like this with some of the attributes listed as extras for the intent?

```
Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```