# Embed Youtube video inside an Android app

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview, android-youtube-api

I'm using a WebView for displaying embedded Youtube video and that works on Galaxcy S2 (OS 2.3.5) and doesn't on Nexus S (OS 2.3.4), all I get is white screen without any video display.

Here is the code snippet I'm using and the declarations in Manifest file:

```
private WebView wv;

private void setWebView()
{
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 

wv.getSettings();

wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

wv.setKeepScreenOn(true);

wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

final String mimeType = "text/html";
final String encoding = "UTF-8";
String html = getHTML();

wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");

}


public String getHTML()
{

String html = "<html>"

    + "<head>"
 + "</head>"
 + "<body style=\"border: 0; padding: 0\">"
 + "<iframe "
 + "type=\"text/html\" "
 + "class=\"youtube-player\" "
 + "width= 100%\""
 + "\" "
 + "height= 95%\""
 + "\" "
 + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/"
 + selected_video 
    + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&modestbranding=0" +
 "&autoplay=1&fs=1&vq=hd720\" " + "frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>" 
    + "</body>"
    + "</html>";

 return html;
}
```

Note: the parameter "selected_video" is the hash of the video (VideoID).

The declarations in Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
.
.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"  />

<application
   .
   .
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"  >

    .
    .
```

Please let me know in case you recognizing anything I should change in my code, or help with a complete code which can support all Android devices and OS for displaying embedded (In-App) Youtube video with high quality.

UPDATE:
Pay attention, the solution I'm looking for should display high resolution video. I got it work on the different devices and OS using VideoView class but the video quality isn't good enough. So any solution including VideoView or WebView or any other way will be accepted only if it makes high quality YouTube video to be displayed. Thanks to all the responders!

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be flash prob, Flash is installed in Nexus S ???                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791035/what-does-install-flash-plugin-in-webview-mean

Comment: I could use other apps that does the same on my Nexus S. I don't want flash to be a must to use the app...

Comment: I mean I think it does not work because Youtube requires Flash, please check if the devices can browse the YouTube site and watch movies? and Let me know the result (do not try YouTube app just youtube site) maby ather app use, youtube android player?  https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: I can see a movie on youtube site without using the app.

Comment: webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); is a deprecated method try targeting min SDK version 8 (2.2) and setting webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

Comment: But this is exactly what I did...

Comment: As hinted by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036415/android-webview-cannot-render-youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe it may not be possible. Have you looked at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 45):

there is an official [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) wich you can use. This is a bit more complicated but it is working better than other solutions using webclients.

First you must register your app in [Googles API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). This is completely free until your app gets over 25k request a month (or something like that). There are complete anf great tutorials under the link. I hope you can understand them. If not, ask! :)

Comment: Thanks! How silly of me i couldn't find there's an API for youtube. Lol

Comment: Youtube android player api require youtube app installed and google play service, but Embed Youtube video for run on every device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67406221/13146544 please help me if possible.. The time bar in Minimal player style is not working.

Comment: Be cereful with YouTube Android Player API. It will be deprecated after May 1, 2023.

Comment: how to remove/hide next and previous button using iframe in android? i am refering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855620/how-can-we-remove-hide-the-next-and-previous-arrow-icons-from-youtube-iframe but it is not helpful for android.

Answer (score 8):

**How it looks:**

[image]

Best solution to my case. I need video fit web view size.
**Use embed youtube link with your video id.**
**Example:**

```
WebView youtubeWebView; //todo find or bind web view
String myVideoYoutubeId = "-bvXmLR3Ozc";

youtubeWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });

WebSettings webSettings = youtubeWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

youtubeWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + myVideoYoutubeId);
```

**WebView xml code**

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

although I suggest to use youtube api or call new intent and make the system handle it (i.e. youtube app), here some code that can help you, it has a call to an hidden method because you can't pause and resume webview

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.app.Activity;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MultimediaPlayer extends Activity
{
    private WebView mWebView;
    private boolean mIsPaused = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        String media_url = VIDEO_URL;

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
        ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mIsPaused = true;
        resumeBrowser();
        mWebView.loadUrl(media_url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        pauseBrowser();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        resumeBrowser();
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void pauseBrowser()
    {
        if (!mIsPaused)
        {
            // pause flash and javascript etc
            callHiddenWebViewMethod(mWebView, "onPause");
            mWebView.pauseTimers();
            mIsPaused = true;
        }
    }

    private void resumeBrowser()
    {
        if (mIsPaused)
        {
            // resume flash and javascript etc
            callHiddenWebViewMethod(mWebView, "onResume");
            mWebView.resumeTimers();
            mIsPaused = false;
        }
    }

    private void callHiddenWebViewMethod(final WebView wv, final String name)
    {
        try
        {
            final Method method = WebView.class.getMethod(name);
            method.invoke(mWebView);
        } catch (final Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It works like this:

```
String item = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";

String ss = "your url";
ss = ss.substring(ss.indexOf("v=") + 2);
item += ss;
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int w1 = (int) (metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density), h1 = w1 * 3 / 5;
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

try {
    wv.loadData(
    "<html><body><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html5\" width=\""
    + (w1 - 20)
    + "\" height=\""
    + h1
    + "\" src=\""
    + item
    + "\" frameborder=\"0\"\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></body></html>",
                            "text/html5", "utf-8");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private WebChromeClient chromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
            if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                frame.removeView(video);
                video.start();
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile (metrics should be Metrics). What should be on "your url" exactly? can you provide a better example?

Comment: What does this line exactly do?                 frame.removeView(video);

Answer (score 0):

The video quality depends upon the Connection speed using API

alternatively for other than API means without YouTube app you can follow this [link](http://blog.erayince.com.tr/?p=202#codesyntax_1)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple: Just put it inside a static method.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(linkYouTube)));
```