# How can we remove/hide the next and previous arrow icons from YouTube iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, youtube

[image]

This is my iframe

```
<iframe
width="100vw"
className="video-frame"
title="Video"
src={url}
frameBorder="0"
controls="0"
autoplay="0"
showinfo="0"
allowFullScreen
/>
```

Please suggest a way to remove the next and previous icons from the YouTube player that I am using in my website.

Also, is there any listener that listens if the video has ended ?

Answer (score 1):

you can access the iframe elements.

for example:

```
<iframe id="frameId" src="/abcd.html" style="height:380px;width:100%"></iframe>
```

then in parent

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsById("closeBtn")[0];
elmnt.style.display = "none";
```

find the close button ids in youTube frame then change the attributes based on your requirement

Comment: What you mean by in parent ?

Comment: simpler like document in child but it's use to call parent node

Comment: how to get "document" ?