# Android Development - Include Flash?

Tags: android, flash, sdk, insert

I need to develop an app for a website. The problem is that on the site are Flash videos.
Is there a way to integrate the Flash in my Android app?

Thank you!

Comment: Flash players have been pretty well phased out for android devices.   Not sure how feasible it is, but you might want to start looking into using html5 video instead of flash for future compatibility.

Comment: Do you know what codecs are inside the FLV containers? It could already be H.264 video codecs (with AAC or MP3 audio) so it just a matter of transferring to an MP4 container instead for HTML5/Android compatibilty. Download **[MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)** and drag one or two of the FLV files into it for feedback. Let me know..

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that you don't as Android is phased out as mentioned. Depending on the complexity, it would be best to replace flash videos with HTML5 where possible.

If you insist on it however, it's possible as long as the user has the Flash plugin installed using a WebView:
[How to Enable Flash Plugin in Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943947/how-to-enable-flash-plugin-in-webview)

Also note that the flash plugin is fairly limited - it has performance and sound sync issues and does not respond to clicks and key presses like the desktop version of flash does (Though oddly, the old Windows Mobile version was quite performant and had no key or mouse issues... huh)